# How do I get Visual Studio 2012 to generate code from a windows form design?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add a simple windows form to my VB.Net project.  I have used the designer to design the form how I want it with buttons, a text box and a Timer.  The problem is when I try to view the code, there is only an empty class that looks like this:

```
Public Class MCastMain

End Class
```

I have set the application type to a windows form application in the project properties, and I have made a successful build of the application since doing so.  I have been scrawling the internet and this forum for about half an hour now and I can't find one other person who is having this problem, nor can I find a tutorial that mentions any special steps that must be taken beyond what I have done.  This is the first project I have done in Visual Studio.

I know this is probably stupid simple, but I have no idea what to do.  Any help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms comes as [partial class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350.aspx) meaning the code is separated in two files.
The "empty" code you shown is from **"mcastmain.vb"** (if the file is named as the class).
With that one there is a (probably hidden) file **"mcastmain.designer.vb"** file which contains the generated code by the designer ; and is not meant to be modified (as any designer change will rewrite the file).
To show the hidden files you have to look in the solution explorer on the button on it's top there should be a "show all files" button. (it may be possible to do the same via the menu but I don't have VS right there to be sure where)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the generated code is all there in the .designer.vb file.  So now I just implement all my logic in the empty .vb class and the compiler will combine the two files?

Comment: @SamHazleton Yes ; the two (or more) files are merged during build (see linked documentation for details)